# PHP select filter

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I have a page with list of persons.

Now I want to filter them with a drop down select.

Here's my code:

```
<main>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="team-list">
            <h3><?php echo $teamTitle; ?></h3>
            <div class="filter">
                <label for="filter"><?php echo $specialtiesTitle; ?></label>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-item">
                        <select name="specialties">
                        <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM specialties";
                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        echo '<option selected="selected" value="All">'. $filterTitle . '</option>';

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $id = $row['id'];   
                            $title = $row['title_'.$lang];

                            echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $title . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-item">
                        <input class="form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $filterSubmit; ?>">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            <?php   
            $query = "SELECT * FROM team";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $image = $row['image'];
                $title = $row['title_'.$lang];  

                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="image"><img src="/uploads/' . $image . '"></div>';
                echo '<a class="title" href="/team-view?id=' . $id . '">' . $title . '</a>';
                echo '<a class="more" href="/team-view?id=' . $id . '">' . $teamMore . '</a>'; 
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
         </div>     
    </div>
</main>
```

As you can see from the code the first part has the div filter that receives select from the database.

This line: 
`echo '<option selected="selected" value="All">'. $filterTitle . '</option>';`

Is a additional option with value "All" and the other options are getting from the "specialties" table.

The second part is the content that pulls from the "team" table. 
I'm relating the categories from "Specialties" table with the "Team" table.

In the Admin area of my Custom CMS, everything is working and when I change the "Specialties" category, it saves successfully in the database.

Right now the page displays all the fields, but I don't have functionality of filtering.

How can I filter the content?

I know that I have to use:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   //the code inside
}
```

but what query should I use for such filtering?

**EDIT:**
By filtering I mean, when I have the list content and from top I have a select drop down and search button. So if I select let's say the first value from the options and click on submit, it should display only the content that has the first category value inside.

In the table "Team" I have many fields and these are the connection:

```
id
specialties_bg
specialties_en
```

This is the table "Specialties"

```
id
title_bg
title_en
```

Title_bg and title_en has all the options values and id is the connection.

The website is multilingual and that's why I have two fields for different languages.

Comment: What do you mean filtering can you explain exactly what you want to filter exactly???

Comment: `$id = $row['id']; ` <- this line grabs values for the select box, but when you build the <option>, you set value to `$search` instead of `$id`

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai I mean when you have a list page, there's a search drop menu and when you choose one from the drop down and click on Submit, it should filter the content. It's a like a search engine, but not with search terms, but with select values.

Comment: @user2519032 : Ahaa..You mean that and your content is stored in where?? I mean in an array sort of or from where???

Comment: The content is stored in the database in "Team" table. On that table there's "specialty" field that's related with the "Specialties" table and with their id, I'm making the connection.

Comment: Well for to filter something like that it's very easy you must should have something common in all of your matching records so that you can target the data through that data i.e having a column similar or anything at all..!

Comment: what is the relation between Specialties and Team table? do you have some filed representing/linking Specialties table to Team table?

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy I've updated the main thread. Please check it out.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I left that $search from old code by mistake. I've edited now and its $id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code. If the form is submitted add a condition to the query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM team";
// declare the variable
// check if the form is submitted and have a valid search value
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && (trim($_POST['specialties'])!='') && (trim($_POST['specialties'])!='ALL')) {
   //add the condition
   $query.= " WHERE specialties_en='".trim($_POST['specialties'])."'";
 }
```

You can modify condition based on the languages with OR condition.

Always check the user input for sql injections.

Comment: I've just tried your example. This line `$query.= ' WHERE specialties_en="'.trim($_POST['specialties']).'";` has syntax error. Also, are you sure that you can use PHP function inside the MySQL query?

Comment: Yes we can use php with mysql. check the edited answer.

Comment: I've used your code, but it doesn't do anything when I choose some select option value and after clicking on submit button. It doesn't have any syntax error. I guess I'm missing something. Also, when I click the submit button, the drop down select is return to the default value "All". Here's a link of the full code from that page: http://paste.ofcode.org/bKCGiRhgFqMViSyASx2m5w

Comment: your code is not correct. I have edited. check this http://paste.ofcode.org/pQBhSM7hixHJ6wptGhes2z

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working great! I've checked the new code and I can see the other changes too. I've learned something very valuable, thanks to you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111053/discussion-between-ravinder-reddy-and-user2519032).

Comment: Its my pleasure to help.

Comment: There was a mistake on your last code on line 54. The value should be "All", not  "ALL". With that error when I click on submit when the value is All option, it returns empty page. That's fixed, now only left to save the value on the filter after clicking submit. Right now if I choose the option, let's say "Dermatology" after submitting the form, it filters the content well, but the select returns the "All" value instead of the "Dermatology" option.

Answer (score 1):

## Fetching Specific Data From Database :

In order to fetch all data from a table you can do that simply by using `SELECT` Query in `MySQL` as :

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

But as now you want to filter the whole data and just get something specific from your database so for that you must should have something unique in order to differentiate the expected data from the whole rest of the data.

### TWO WAYS TO DO THAT :

**1) Using An Extra Field (Column) In Your Database Table :**

You can do that by adding an extra field (column) to your table structure like something which will contain values based on the records in order to put them in a collective based group.

**For Instance :**
I have a table with alot of records of players now I add a column namely as sport so now I have something unique in order to filter the players.So I can use following SQL `SELECT` Query to get all those players as:

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE sport="sport_name";
```

**2) Filtering Data Through PHP :**

If you don't want to get the filtered data from the Database,So you can do the same process in PHP also as:

**For Instance :**

You already fetched the whole data from the `players` table and now you want to filter it so you can filter it like this way as :

```
<?php
//Assuming that $results contains the whole fetched data from table
for ($i=0;$i<=count($results);$i++) {
   if ($results[$i]['sport'] == "cricket") { 
      // Can target any sport located in your database
      //You can pretty much do anything you want..!
      echo $result[$i]['player_name'];
   }
}
?>
```